# Powershell does not capture EXE exception when run as a scheduled task

Tags: powershell

I am executing a .Net program using a Powershell script. When I run the script in the ISE it captures exception messages in the $output variable. When I execute the same script as a scheduled task, $output is an empty array. The scheduled task command is:

```
cmd /c "powershell.exe -File C:\ScheduledJobs\MyScript.ps1" > job.log 2>&1
```

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
try
{
    $output = C:\Utilities\SomeDotNetProgram.exe /s:"SOME_STORED_PROCEDURE" 2>&1
}
catch
{
    Write-Host "+++", $output.Count, "---"
    $From = "Database Administrator <xxx@xxx.com>"
    $To = "xxx@xxx.com"
    $Subject = "Scheduled task failed"
    $Body = -join $output
    if ($output.Count -eq 0)
        {$body = "??"} #Only gets here when run as scheduled task
    $SMTPServer = "mail.xxx.net"
    $SMTPPort = "25"
    Send-MailMessage -From $From -to $To -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -port $SMTPPort
}
```

How can I make this work in a scheduled task?
This is running on Windows Server 2012 R2.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT to clarify:** The likely reason that it fails is that a program calling a program calling a program will not necessarily transfer permissions over. Even if the first call to CMD is running as administrator that doesn't mean the subsequent process will too. Removing as many nested calls as possible will reduce potential problems.

**Original answer:**

It looks like your scheduled task is running CMD that then calls the powershell script. You don't need to do that, you can run the powershell script directly in Task Scheduler.

Set the action in Task Scheduler to run the program `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe` and in the 'Add Arguments' box you enter `-File "C:\ScheduledJobs\MyScript.ps1"` including double quotation marks. You may also need to change the execution policy by adding `-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` depending on if the script is signed or not. If this is a demo/lab environment you could also use Bypass although that is not recommended in production environments.

I've had similar issues when trying to run CMD that then runs Powershell so just running the script as it is will probably solve your issue.

Comment: I used cmd so I could redirect stdout and stderr to a file in addition to handling the error in the script. I tried "powershell.exe -File C:\ScheduledJobs\MyScript.ps1" (no quotes) and got the the same result.

Comment: It is not a permission problem since the program will run correctly. I just can't capture error information when I force an exception by intentionally passing in a bad parameter.

Comment: I had the exact same situation when trying to run a Powershell script from a VBA script. The program would run on it's own, but wouldn't produce output when called from VBA. The reason was the ExecutionPolicy blocking it but it wouldn't tell me that. If you want to output to file you can pipe the output to Out-File instead of storing it as a variable, as in C:\Utilities\SomeDotNetProgram.exe /s:"SOME_STORED_PROCEDURE" 2>&1 | Out-File "C:\somefile.txt".

Comment: So far nothing has worked.  I have to put this on hold for awhile but I will be back.

Comment: One thing that has worked for me previously was the following:  -File "C:\ScheduledJobs\MyScript.ps1" -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned. As in, you force the script to use RemoteSigned as the Execution Policy (because using Bypass is sometimes restricted on systems). If you have some progress here let me know and I'll see if I can help further.